# JPA Query to Return a Map

Tags: java

I wrote the following JPA method that queries a database to return a distinct list of a String field (called mtfcc) of a Location object. I then took the list of strings to query for the associated name for that MTFCC.

Could I just modify the first query to get the results, without having to use the for loop to get the associated name field?

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getAvailableBorderTypes() {

    // create empty map to store results in. If we don't find results, an empty hashmap will be returned
    Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    // get the distinct mtfcc's
    String jpaQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT location.mtfcc FROM Location location";

    // get the distinct mtfcc codes
    List<String> mtfccList = (List<String>) em.createQuery(jpaQuery).getResultList();

    // cycle through the mtfcc list and get the name to associate with it
    for (String mtfcc: mtfccList) {
        String nameQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT location.name FROM Location location WHERE location.mtfcc = ?1";
        String name = (String) em.createQuery(nameQuery).setParameter(1, mtfcc).getSingleResult();
        results.put(mtfcc, name);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about JPA and which queries it supports, but wouldn't it already be faster to do `SELECT location FROM Location location` and do the distinct programmatically? Not saying this is the best solution, but right now you are querying all locations twice.

Comment: It's a performance issue. Location could potentially have hundreds of thousands of rows in the database.

Comment: So I'm guessing JPA allows you to use indexes? Otherwise it would be a memory issue, and not as much a performance issue.

Comment: Again, I might be entirely wrong here, but what about `SELECT DISTINCT location.mtfcc, location.name FROM Location location`. :) Perhaps consider phrasing this as a question on distinct on Stack Overflow if you don't get any knowledgeable responses here.

Comment: I've considered it, but I'm having a major brain fart in my query-fu here trying to decide it it would work. I think it would, so I'll just have to try it once the code is runnable.

Comment: @Steven: The query would work, but JPA has a difficult time working with specific columns. It really was designed for entities stored as a whole row. I've found a possible solution, but haven't been able to prove it yet. :)

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595328/jpa-2-0-native-query-results-as-map/46190527#46190527

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I've got a possible simplification for you. The goal I had was to get to using one query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location.mftcc, location.name FROM Location location
```

It turns out that `Query.getResultList()` behaves funny: It returns a `List` of `Object[]`! Each entry in the list represents a row returned from the database, where the entries in the Object[] are each field specified in the SELECT. Also, to furthur complicate matters, each field is returned as the JPA type. So, you have to treat the whole array as an `Object[]` and cast the individual elements.

Here's the code to get it to work:

```
public Map<String, String> getAvailableBorderTypes() {
   // create empty map to store results in. If we don't find results, an empty hashmap will be returned
   Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();

   EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

   // Construct and run query
   String jpaQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT location.mftcc, location.name FROM Location location";
   List<Object[]> resultList = em.createQuery(jpaQuery).getResultList();

   // Place results in map
   for (Object[] borderTypes: resultList) {
      results.put((String)borderTypes[0], (String)borderTypes[1]);
   }

   return results;
}
```

Comment: JPA (the Java API, anyway) is also pretty undocumented. I had to use reflection just to find out the return type. Fun exercise!